# Trying to get the value of a picker's selectedItem within a listview (MVVM)

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

Need some direction/help here guys.  Similar to a basic contacts app - I'm building a customer entry screen and need a drop down for contact types (phone, email, etc). I figured out how to populate the picker(s) by explicitly defining the path and source but I can't seem to get SelectedItem to do anything. My expectation is set the default value of the picker with whats in the record and also be able to change that value.

```
<ListView x:Name="ContactListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Customer.ContactList}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <StackLayout>
                            <Picker
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ContactTypes, Source={x:Reference ContactListView} }"
                                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding TypeName}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding TypeName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            />
                        <Entry Text="{Binding Value}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The ViewModel attached to this page is a Customer object which has a nested contact list in it (defined at the list view). Below is a basic version of the Customer Class that I'm using on the page with its relationship to ContactTypes.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> ContactList { get; set; }
}

public class ContactType
{
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public int SortOrderId { get; set; }
}

public class Contact : ContactType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

When the Page ViewModel loads, I store a list of possible ContactTypes (one time) that the user can choose from and it's shared in each picker as the item source. The list of possible ContactTypes from the database are stored in a local variable - here's the static representation of it:

```
public IList<ContactType> ContactTypes { get; } = new List<ContactType>
{
    new ContactType(){ TypeName = "Home Phone", SortOrderId = 1  },
    new ContactType(){ TypeName = "Cell Phone", SortOrderId = 2 },
    new ContactType(){ TypeName = "Work Phone", SortOrderId = 3 },
    new ContactType(){ TypeName = "Email", SortOrderId = 4 },
    new ContactType(){ TypeName = "Fax", SortOrderId = 5 }
};
```

I need the picker to show the options from ContactTypes, and when an Item is Selected, it updates the TypeName property of the current record iteration in ContactList.